# In App Billing Subscription , check if subscribed

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to do a check if a user is subscribed to the app ,

My question is - is it possible to check it without entering a sku ?

this is what i'm doing now:

```
  IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, final Inventory inventory) {
        if(inventory.hasPurchase(skutmp)) {
            return true;
}
```

What i want to do is to check if there are any purchases (without using a sku)

Is there any way to do so ?

EDIT :

The main idea is to do so without getting a list from my server , so is there maybe a way to get the products available in the store so i could check them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone need help with that I managed to find this link

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

You basically need to set it up and than do

```
Bundle activeSubs = mService.getPurchases(3, "com.example.myapp",
               "subs", null);
```

The bundle at place 0 will contain an ArrayList with all your purchases so what I did is check the size of the ArrayList.

Comment: how to get bundle at position 0? I am getting the bundle object .